# Getting Broadcast twice for a single incoming call in 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I am getting EXTRA_STATE_RINGING broadcast twice for a single call in android 4.1.2. For version below this it works fine. I have tried with abortBroadcast and unRegisterBroadcast() but nothing works with version 4.1.2. I have searched for other similar questions and tried with all but didn't got any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you would like to get only one broadcast for single call, right?

Comment: I got the solution, but this is not the correct way. May be there is any other solution but i didn't got the solution So i used this - I set a preference on EXTRA_STATE_RINGING with true and do required task and then again set this preference with false so next time my code does not executes. And on EXTRA_STATE_IDLE again set the preference with true.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced double broadcasts on the Google Nexus 4 (Android 4.2). I have been working on a similar solution (based on the `SharedPreferences`) but as it soon  turned out it wasn't reliable and of course was slow because of  the disk I/O usage. Finally I've created the `Service` which was "filterning" callbacks from  the BroadcastReceiver.

```
// Service

boolean callInProgress;

// listener callbacks
public void onPhoneStateChange(boolean state) {

if (state)  {
        if (!callInProgress)    {

            // do something when the first broadcast arrives.
        callInProgress = true;  
     } 
} else  {
        callInProgress = false;
        // called when the call ends.
    }

}

// Service
```